# Setting up an SVN user

Tags: ubuntu, svn, configuration

I want to add a user in svn on an Ubuntu machine, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: What kind of svn server do you have? file, svn, http?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your SVN repo (note: **not** the checkout) there is a directory called "`conf`". In that directory are a few files that control users and their access to the repo:

- `svnserve.conf`
- `passwd`
- `authz`

Read the notes at the top of those files and you should be able to add a new user and configure their read/write access to the repo.

Answer (score 2):

In case you are using HTTP/WebDAV access:

1. Locate the htpasswd file you use for listing users.  This path can be found in the apache configuration for your server - grep for the word *AuthUserFile*.
2. Enter *htpasswd thepathtothatfile theusernametoadd*
3. When prompted enter the new password for the user, and repeat it to confirm.
4. Now restart/graceful the apache instance controlling your repository (propably something like *apache2ctl -k graceful*

The user should now be active on the repository.  If you also have per-directory access control set up, follow these steps as well:

1. Locate your per-directory permissions file - grep your apache config for the term *AuthzSVNAccessFile* ; this will give you the path (if it is set).
2. Either add a directory to the file (*[/directory/from/root/of/repo]*), or select an existing entry.
3. Add that user underneath the appropriate entry, specifying *rw* for full access, or *r* for read-only.

Here is a sample per-directory access file:

```
[/]
admin = rw

[/project/trunk]
sarah = rw
mike = r
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a few examples that does what you want. It does however depend on how subversion was installed (web or no web).

http://www.howtoforge.com/subversion-trac-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-server

Comment: The first link is to a not suitable for work site.

Comment: link removed. (guess domain has a new owner)

Answer (score 1):

Go to conf Directory in your repo

Open svnserver.conf and uncomment/add these lines if they are already not.
anon-access = read
auth-access = write
password-db = passwd

Open file named passwd in conf directory to add users, one way to add users easily is to add a line for the new user account in the format "user=password" (no quotes) to the file

Hope that helps .. :)

Thanks,
Mahesh Velaga.